# pg_basebackup from docker postgres container and restoring to physical postgres

Tags: postgresql, backup, docker

I am using pg_basebackup to backup data that is running in docker based postgres (alpine) to a physical postgresql cluster. Both postgres versions are 12.

`docker exec -t postgresql pg_basebackup -U postgres -D /backup -Ft -z -Z5 -P`

`docker cp postgresql:/backup .`

I am trying to restore the physical cluster with this backup data. I am getting a lot of weird errors. postgresql is not restoring correctly.

Is it possible to use backup from docker container to physical postgres ? will it work ?

Is it better to do with pg_dumpall ?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. I guess you'll need to show us some of those weird errors, for us to able to supply you with an answer. I'm not aware of any restrictions regarding the backup and restore of database that are run in containers. But without more information we will be just poking around in the dark.Could be a docker issue. Could be a PostgreSQL issue. Hit [edit]  and add more details to your question. Thanks.

Comment: A basebackup **only** works if the major version of the target Postgres is the same **and** if both are running the same operating system.

Comment: @JohnK.N. Thank you. I figured it out. It worked... I forgot to create the .signal file and a small mistake in the restore command to copy the wal archive to pg_wal directory.

Comment: please write this up as answer.